# Dealing with generic tree keys

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I need generic interface for handling trees. For example:

```
class ITreeNode<TKey>
{
    TKey Id {get; set;}
    TKey? ParentId {get; set;} // okay for numeric types, but what about strings?
}

class ITreeNode<TKey>
{
    TKey Id {get; set;}
    TKey ParentId {get; set;} // again okay for strings, but what about numeric types?
}
```

How to deal with the typing of the properties if the generic type parameter has to support primitive types and classes, like `string`? Entities are saved to database using entity framework, so I cannot do something wild like `bool HasParent` (foreign keys).

Comment: "*How to deal with it*" is a fairly broad question. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Are you after the equivalent of `Nullable<T>`, but something that also works with reference types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this the hard way, by having three interfaces: one non-generic variant, one generic for primitive types (like `int`, `bool`, etc.) and one for the rest (classes).

Some code:

```
interface ITreeNodeNG
{
    object Id { get; set; }

    object ParentId { get; set; }
}

interface ITreeNodeP<TKey> where TKey : struct
{
    TKey? Id { get; set; }

    TKey? ParentId { get; set; }
}
interface ITreeNodeC<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }

    TKey ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class X : ITreeNodeP<int>, ITreeNodeNG
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    object ITreeNodeNG.Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Id;
        }

        set
        {
            this.Id = (int)value;
        }
    }

    object ITreeNodeNG.ParentId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ParentId;
        }

        set
        {
            this.ParentId = (int?)value;
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ITreeNodeNG x = new X();
    ITreeNodeP<int> y = new X();
    ITreeNodeC<string> z = null; // you know what to do
}
```

The sample class `X` implements both the non-generic and the primitive interface. This will give you the possibility to get the ID without knowing the exact type of the interface. Your `X` class could be an (abstract) base class if you want to.

Comment: Thanks, ```object NodeId``` was enough for me. Apparently my mind was too strongly typed to figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've guessing you want something like the `Maybe<T>` class - it's the equivalent of `Nullable<T>`, but it works with reference types too.

```
public interface ITreeNode<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
    Maybe<TKey> ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

It's a simple definition:

```
public class Maybe<T>
{
    public readonly static Maybe<T> Nothing = new Maybe<T>();

    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }

    public Maybe()
    {
        HasValue = false;
    }

    public Maybe(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        HasValue = true;
    }

    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T v)
    {
        return v.ToMaybe();
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public class TreeNode<TKey> : ITreeNode<TKey>
{
    public TreeNode(TKey id)
        : this(id, Maybe<TKey>.Nothing)
    { }

    public TreeNode(TKey id, Maybe<TKey> parentId)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ParentId = parentId;
    }

    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public Maybe<TKey> ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And then this:

```
ITreeNode<int> a = new TreeNode<int>(5);
ITreeNode<int> b = new TreeNode<int>(5, 1);
ITreeNode<string> c = new TreeNode<string>("q1");
ITreeNode<string> d = new TreeNode<string>("q2", "q1");
```

Then you can check if there is a parent with `a.ParentId.HasValue` or `d.ParentId.HasValue`, etc.

This is a useful extension class to go with it:

```
public static class MaybeEx
{
    public static Maybe<T> ToMaybe<T>(this T value)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>(value);
    }

    public static Maybe<U> Select<T, U>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T, U> k)
    {
        return m.SelectMany(t => k(t).ToMaybe());
    }

    public static Maybe<U> SelectMany<T, U>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T, Maybe<U>> k)
    {
        if (!m.HasValue)
        {
            return Maybe<U>.Nothing;
        }
        return k(m.Value);
    }

    public static Maybe<V> SelectMany<T, U, V>(this Maybe<T> @this, Func<T, Maybe<U>> k, Func<T, U, V> s)
    {
        return @this.SelectMany(x => k(x).SelectMany(y => s(x, y).ToMaybe()));
    }
}
```